# Ansible AWX: LDAP mapping for organization, teams, project

Tags: ansible, ldap, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I am setting up LDAP settings in Ansible AWX. I want to achieve 3 things in ldap settings for organization, teams and projects :

1. All XYZ team members should be super admin (DONE)
2. Organization permission should be group level (not user level)
3. All teams (expect one - XYZ) should be admin to their team organization and projects.

I achieved point(1) by using following mapping in LDAP User Flags by Group:

```json
    {
      "is_superuser": [
             "CN=XYZ,OU=myorg,OU=security,OU=xyz,DC=ad,DC=com"
          ]
    }
```

My LDAP organisation map is as follows:

```json
    {
      "Services": {
        "admins": [
          "CN=prod_root_sudo,OU=Servers,OU=Unix,OU=Groups,OU=Users & Groups,OU=DS,OU=DSSI,DC=ad,DC=com",
          "CN=preprod_root_sudo,OU=Servers,OU=Unix,OU=Groups,OU=Users & Groups,OU=DS,OU=DSSI,DC=ad,DC=com"
        ],
        "remove_admins": true,
        "remove_users": true,
        "users": [
          "CN=ABC,OU=myorg,OU=security,OU=aes,OU=xyz,DC=ad,DC=com"
        ]
     }
```

and LDAP team map is :

```json
    {
      "Team1": {
        "organization": "Services",
        "remove": true,
        "users": [
          "CN=grp,OU=myorg,OU=security,DC=ad,DC=com",
        ]
      }
     }
```

What changes should I do to achieve point 2 and 3?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!